# apple doc for LSHandlerContentType?

Tags: osx-el-capitan

I'm trying to set SublimeText as the default editor for any unknown extension.

I'm aware that I can define the opening application for a given extension, but I would like to set a default application for the case the extension is unknown (which happens a lot if you name your files extensions manually).

The obvious solution in my case is rather to name the new files with a known extension like txt, but just for the sake of knowing whether or not it's possible to have a default application for all, I was looking for the LSHandlerContentType key in google and couldn't find any apple documentation page explaining what this key does.

So my question is: where is the LSHandlerContentType's official documentation page?

(I tried google without success)

Answer (score 3):

LSHandlers are set per content-type for the individual items. There isn't a catchall. You'll need to run `mdls` on one and see what `kMDItemContentType` is and set the LSHandler appropriately with something along the following vein:

```
defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSHandlers -array-add '{LSHandlerContentType=xxxType;LSHandlerRoleAll=xxx.yyy.sublime;}'
```

For example, if the content type is a plain text file, it'd be as follows:

```
defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSHandlers -array-add {LSHandlerContentType=public.plain-text;LSHandlerRoleAll=com.sublimetext.2;}
```

You can review more information on the lsregister here: http://krypted.com/mac-security/lsregister-associating-file-types-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: Massive thanks for mentioning the tool `mdls` for getting the ContentType! Now I know how to fish.